# Using MVVMCross to bind to error messages

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am new to MVVMCross (and mobile in general) and I am looking to implement binding to error messages (like FluentValidation ValidationResults or IDataErrorInfo).

Preferably, I would like an Errors like dictionary that I can bind directly to:
`bind(label).To(vm => vm.Errors["Name"])`

I have tried an ObservableDictionary (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx), but I am not getting notified when the ViewModel adds errors.

As expected, wrapping access as a property in the view model works, but could get cumbersome: 
`public string NameError { get { return Errors.ContainsKey("Name") ? Errors["Name"] : null; } }`

I have also considered creating a custom binding, but am not sure how to get access to the ViewModel and pass the field name I want. Seems like I could pass Errors or the property name.

Finally, since invalid conversions (i,e. 22ab for an int) are not pushed down into the view model, is there a way to get those errors? Should I be validating before data gets pushed back to the view model instead? Like textFieldShouldEndEditing or ShouldChangeCharacters on iOS? I could wrap a custom control if necessary.

What techniques are others using with Xamarin/MVVMCross using to provide validation feedback?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: still looking at this - will try to set up a test harness and app later... just busy with work right now...

Comment: further update - think this might be part of the fix... https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/commit/5ecd43532a59ec16c77d3770ed17c2273fb6794d - still investigating and getting the unit test in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MvvmCross doesn't currently implement the IDataErrorInfo level of data-binding

This is mainly because no-one has yet asked for it - but I guess that might just change with this question. If you do have specific requirements, then the project would be interested to hear them - suspect the best place for that is github issues for the project.

For your specific questions...

---

The approach of binding to an `ObservableDictionary` which implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` should work.

<strike>However, looking at the code in your link, I don't think that dictionary is correctly implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` - in addition to the `INotifyCollectionChanged` events, it should also be raising the property change notifications on `Count` and `Item[]` - without these the binding to the whole set will work, but not to individual items and to count. For an example source of ObservableCollection, see https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Collections.ObjectModel/ObservableCollection.cs</strike>

Looking a second time at the code in your link, it appears that the dictionary is correctly implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` - it is raising the property change notifications `Item[]` - and this is the string required for the individual items to bind. Do you have debug trace enabled? Does the trace give you any clue about why it is failing?

I've submitted some fixes today - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/345 - and have tested them in this sample - [Test_WithErrors.axml](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Droid/Resources/Layout/Test_WithErrors.axml) - I would expect this same sample should work on iOS (the iOS test app is a work in progress) and that it should also be extensible for Jeremy's excellent FluentValidation (although I've not used that in PCL form yet)

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter email:"
      />
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text Email"
    />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    local:MvxBind="Text Errors['Email']"
      />
```

Thanks for pointing out this error - fixed binaries will be nuget in the next day or two!

---

On the int-string question, the binding layer currently "does it's best" (TM) to convert UI types to VM types. However, there is no event currently triggered when it fails - so there is no way to fire any validation rules in the ViewModel from the binding.

Instead, where free text input is allowed, I think you'll need to implement the ViewModel types as `string` and will then need to trigger the validation rules when the ViewModel property changes. Because MvvmCross doesn't expose any binding level hooks for when validation occurs, you'll maybe need to tweak when binding occurs (e.g. on first responder resign) rather than having continual validation - but this should be fairly straight-forward using a custom-binding.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back, VS2012 to simulator stops working and I have to create a new project, add all the files and restart. Not sure why?

Debugging with your source, I did change to PropertyNameForChangedEvent and it works as expected. Thanks for the fast turnaround.

Comment: Follow up to the int-string, I plan on doing basic data type checking in shouldChangeCharactersInRange and/or ShouldEndEditing. Then have the rest of the validations happen in the ViewModel. Might try the string on the view model though, I prefer the strong typing, it would be workable.

Comment: OK - thanks - over and out on this question. If you make anything nice - especially using Jeremy's fluent library - then please do blog or github it - would be fab to see!